# Problem using Iptables for filtering traffic on a network interface which is a bridge port, on a specific tcp port

Tags: iptables, network-interface, tcp, bridge

I am using iptables as firewall to filter traffic. I want to block traffic on a network interface on a certain tcp port (I'm testing on port 22). The network interface is a bridge port, so I'm using physdev module (I have tried -i option and it does not work). When I write the rule without specifying any ports, all traffic gets filtered successfully:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m physdev --physdev-in IF_NAME -j DROP
```

But when I specify the port, It doesn't work:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m physdev --physdev-in IF_NAME -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

I have tried mark and connmark modules to split the rules in two, so the bridge interface and tcp port be in separate rules. No luck.

Some clarifications: I'm using iptables v1.8.2 on Debian 10. I'm trying to filter traffic for a VM. I'm writing the rules on host machine. The network interface is set for the VM. If I use VM's IP instead of network interface, it works fine.

Could it be that it doesn't work because the bridge is on data-link layer and tcp ports are in transport layer? I personally don't think this is a good excuse for the rule to not work. After all iptables works on different network layers.

My question:

1. (first priority) Is it possible to make this rule work using iptables? if yes how, and if no why?
2. Is it possible to do so using nftables?
3. Any other solutions you want to mention?

Comment: You will need to filter at L2 with ebtables or a bridge table in nftables, I think. (They allows you to match a bridge port *and* an IP socket.)

Comment: `After all iptables works on different network layers.` Not really btw. Essentially it filters at L3, although it allows you to match than more just src/dst IPs. Bridge ports aren't really considered "logical" interfaces under the context. In other words you can only "filter *at* the bridge". Which bridge port do the traffics come from is "transparent".

Comment: Using physdev makes iptables receive IPv4 bridged traffic (in complement of routed traffic). The ether type IPv4 frames are temporarily transformed into ip packets for iptables "compatibility" by the br_netfilter kernel module (autoloaded by physdev, or also by Docker). But using this will have side effects elsewhere. It would indeed be better to use nftables in the bridge family since it supports directly stateful firewalling there. I don't know why your rules don't work but as usual, you should provide a reproducible setup so we can debug (network setup + `iptables-save -c`)

Comment: And you should clarify what you want to block: block the VM from accessing SSH on other VMs in its LAN and the host+Internet? (that's what I understood) Only one of these? In an other direction?

Comment: @TomYan `In other words you can only "filter at the bridge". Which bridge port do the traffics come from is "transparent"`
It's a bit odd that you can specify bridge port name if it's transparent

Comment: @foadk I apologize. I missed the fact that you are trying to use this `physdev` module which I wasn't aware of / have no experience with. I was purely referring to the fact `-i some_bridge_port` won't do what you might expect.

Comment: @A.B Turns out tcp ports are reversed (or mirrored?) in layer 2 and I should've used --sport instead of --dport

Comment: Only you can tell: you didn't specify what you wanted to block (only that it was using port 22) . Also providing the full ruleset (not the 1 line addition) would have helped.

Comment: @A.B You're right. Anyway, wasn't the little information I provided enough to point out the problem (reversed ports)? Feel free to add an answer and edit the question to make it general enough to fit the answer. (The answer being the reverse thing on layer 2 which I have little knowledge about. By the way, is it the default (or intrinsic) behavior in data link layer?)

Comment: There's nothing about reversing tcp/udp ports in L2 that I know of. It's perhaps just a question of point of view that I can't know because you didn't specify what you wanted to block.